# Connecting with the UITextView UIBoutlet xcode 3.2

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextfield, iboutlet, xcode3.2

I'm trying to connect my IBOutlet UITextView but it can not connect via the Interface Builder, algumém been through this problem? and how do I make this connection with my IBOultlet?. My IBOutlet is declared like this:

the file. ago 
IBOutlet UITextView * notesFields;

the file. m 
@ synthesize notesFields;

thank you[image]

Comment: A UITextView is not a UITextField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using a UITextField rather than a UITextView. Change the IBOutlet declaration to a UITextField.

Comment: thanks for watching, I missed that .. thanks, exchanged and functioned normally

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to mark as answered if this is now solved.